# Show there is a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $K\subset H$ and such that the order of $K$ divides $n!$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ having index $n$. Show there is a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $K\subset H$ and such that the order of $K$ divides $n!$ . any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: This is false. Perhaps you mean the *index* of $K$ divides $n!$?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Well, there's always the trivial subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

This has surely been asked before (with the correction *order* $\to$ *index* noted by **@ChrisEagle**). Anyway, consider the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets of $H$,
$$
g \mapsto (H a \mapsto H a g).
$$
(That is, an element $g \in G$ is mapped to the permutation $Ha \mapsto Hag$ of the cosets of $H$.)

This gives you a homomorphism $\phi$ of $G$ to the symmetric group $S_{n}$. If the image is $T$, then the first isomorphism theorem tells you that
$$
G / \ker(\phi) \cong T \le S_{n}.
$$ 
By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $T$ divides the order $n!$ of $S_{n}$, and then $\lvert T \rvert = \lvert G : \ker(\phi) \rvert$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Let $G$ act on the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ by left multiplication, and consider the kernel of this action.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the action of $G$ on the right cosets of $H$ (by right multiplication); it gives you a morphism $\phi:G \to S_n$ so that the cardinality of $G/Ker(\phi)$ divides $n!$. That kernel is a normal subspace of $G$ contained in $H$ .